# Import dates from Excel to Outlook Calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I am trying to import dates in column "E" to my Outlook calendar.

I have code started, but it is only adding certain dates to my calendar and not adding what it seems to me like multiple dates for ex. The date of 6/2 is being added to my calendar with correct subject date and body, but for dates for 6/1 I have an empty slot.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateOutlookApptz()
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Dim olApp As OUtlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As OUtlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim blnCreated As Boolean
    Dim olNs As OUtlook.Namespace
    Dim CalFolder As OUtlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim subFolder As OUtlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim arrCal As String

    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = OUtlook.Application

    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = OUtlook.Application
         blnCreated = True
        Err.Clear
    Else
        blnCreated = False
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set CalFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    i = 2
    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""

    Set subFolder = CalFolder

    Set olAppt = subFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    MsgBox Cells(i, 6) + Cells(i, 7)

    'MsgBox subFolder, vbOKCancel, "Folder Name"

    With olAppt

    'Define calendar item properties
        .Start = Cells(i, 6) + Cells(i, 7)
        .End = Cells(i, 8) + Cells(i, 9)
        .Subject = Cells(i, 2)
        .Location = Cells(i, 3)
        .Body = Cells(i, 4)
        .BusyStatus = olBusy
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(i, 10)
        .ReminderSet = True
        .Categories = Cells(i, 5)
        .Save

    End With

        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred - Exporting items to Calendar."

End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: It won't add multiple dates because `If olApptSearch Is Nothing Then`. With regards to skipping dates, throw in some `debug.prints` on say `sSubject` but hard to say :/ This will take some step by step debugging.

Comment: @findwindow any suggestions in how I can change olApptSearch to add multiple dates?

Comment: I should confess that I don't use outlook much so that's just my guess. So no, I have no idea :/ Perhaps you can add date as a search criteria?

Comment: @Findwindow Alright looks like I managed to add duplicates now, but I have another error perhaps you might be able to help on this line .End = Cells(i, 8) + Cells(i, 9) I am getting a runtime error stating that the date entered occurs before the start date any idea why this happens if I can clear see I see I set the day one day plus?

Comment: @findwindow sorry I've updated the columns please see picture

Comment: Oh. You're adding dates and time. Um, can you do that? Try wrapping it in `datevalue`?

Comment: @findwindow I added a datevalue and timevalue and clearly set them apart and it's still giving me a error stating my before date comes before my start date

Comment: @findwindow well I not sure exactly what I did, but I used once again a timevalue and closed it and ran it again and it executed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
Private Sub Add_Appointments_To_Outlook_Calendar()

    'Include Microsoft Outlook nn.nn Object Library from Tools -> References
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim Remind_Time As Double

    i = 2
    Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)

    'Loop through entire list of Reminders to be added
    While Subj <> ""
        Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        oAppt.Subject = Subj
        oAppt.Location = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        oAppt.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Remind_Time = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) * 1 * 60
        oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Remind_Time
        oAppt.AllDayEvent = True
        oAppt.Save

        i = i + 1
        Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    Wend
    MsgBox "Reminder(s) Added To Outlook Calendar"

End Sub
```

Your setup will look something like this.

[image]

I talk about this concept, and many other similar, but different, things in my book.

[https://www.amazon.com/Automating-Business-Processes-Reducing-Increasing-ebook/dp/B01DJJKVZC?ie=UTF8&keywords=ryan%20shuell&qid=1464361126&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DJJKVZC)